# Malware infected sites list(only URL)

Tags: web-scraping, malware, malware-detection

I want malware infected sites list (only URL's) any pointers ?

Found some but they don't have option to download the list.

Some sites are:
http://malc0de.com/database/

http://www.malwareblacklist.com/showMDL.php

Copying each and every url from these list is not possible.

Any pointers towards these is appreciated.

Comment: Use Internet Security provided by any antivirus service..

Comment: I want only URL's. I am developing application so I need this .

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find aome lists of malware infected urls:

http://www.hosts-file.net/

http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/

https://github.com/chrisaljoudi/uBlock/issues/1406#issue-80697212 (by Disconnect)

List of lists: https://zeltser.com/malicious-ip-blocklists/

Also take a look at that question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32058/looking-for-url-blacklists-of-malicious-websites

Answer (score 2):

[isc.sans.edu](https://isc.sans.edu/suspicious_domains.html) have text-file lists of suspicious and/or risky domains. Most of the sites there use javascript or java attacks, I've only checked out a few, so there might be more interesting things in there.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old question, but anyone coming here to look for answer can benefit from this new API google published to check a updated list of websites https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/?hl=en